# How to reduce/compress three.js GLTF model size (with .bin and textures)?

Tags: reactjs, three.js, gltf

I am loading a 3d model of a globe for my website and it takes forever to download.

I am using the `GLTFLoader` to load the model inside `React`.

```
  loadModals() {
    const loader = new GLTFLoader()
    loader.load(
      "/models/scene.gltf",
      gltf => {
        object = gltf.scene.children[0]
        scene.add(object)
        console.log("Model loaded")
      },
      xhr => {
        console.log("Model loading...")
      },
      error => {
        console.log("Model failed to load", error)
      }
    )
  }
```

The files relevant to the 3d model include:

- **a textures folder of images (58.7MB)**
- scene.bin (1.2MB)
- scene.gltf (10KB)

From research, it seems like if the model comes with a `.bin` file, it means the `gltf` isnt in compressed binary format. However, looking at tools such as `gltf-pipeline` online, I am not sure how to implement the compression when there are separate files like the textures folder and the `scene.bin`.

I am very new to three.js and implementation in the web, so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to compress your texture there are multiple image compression website.

Why not used .glb format ? GLB file format is a binary form of GLTF that includes textures instead of referencing them as external images.

Sorry if I don't help you.

Comment: The `.glb` conversion would be great! Can you point me to how to do that? I have searched online and I haven't found any that bundles `.gltf`, `.bin`, and the textures folder together.

Comment: I use Blender to export my model in .glb, I suppose it's possible to do the same with others 3D software but I only know Blender ^^

Answer (score -1):

Since I haven't received any answers yet, my temporary solution is to use Photoshop to optimise the images in the textures folder first.

But this comes at a cost for a lower quality appearing model.

Comment: If your images are 60MB in a folder by themselves, then the problem isn't really glTF-specific. Any general image optimization tool (I like https://squoosh.app/) would work here.